# "a specific type of" vs. a "type of"

Tags: expressions

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram:

> Sankey diagrams are a specific type of flow diagram

Isn't saying "a specific type of" redundant? I see that the expression "a specific type of" has [67,900,000 results in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20specific%20type%20of%22&oq=%22a%20specific%20type%20of%22). What is the difference between "X is a type of Y" and "X is a specific type of Y"?

Comment: [COCA results](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/): "a type of" 1698; "a specific type of" 109.

Comment: @snailplane- ok, but how should we interpret that?  I might say that this shows that people are non-specific more often than specific-  which I find intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

It is specific because you can specify it.

I may have a bunch of keys of various types.  Each of them is a type of key, but this one is, specifically, a paracentric key.

One usually follows up with the specific type, for example:

> That's a specific kind of diagram known as a Sankey diagram.

Of course in your usage the name is supplied up front.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Should I conclude from your answer that if the the name is supplied up front, then saying "a specific type of" redundant?

Comment: Possibly, but I think the use of the phrase "is a specific type of" reinforces the fact that the name you've just seen is an accepted name for the type.

Comment: What is the difference between *That's a kind of diagram known as a Sankey diagram* and *That's a `specific` kind of diagram known as a Sankey diagram* ? (Moreover, why would you say that? You'd say, *That's a Sankey diagram.*). But I would suggest *That's a kind of flow diagram known as a Sankey diagram*

Comment: @SrJoven- Suppose your boss came to you and said, "What's this diagram you've drawn, I don't like the way these arrows change size everywhere." You might reply, "I just didn't make it up, that is a specific type of diagram called a Sankey diagram."

Comment: It still doesn't prevent it from being redundant. I'll admit I might say it, but then again, I have no specific reason :) to say it. Here it makes a difference. I might have no reason at all, but if I had no specific reason, I could still have a "general" reason -- I don't have to specify why.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to @Jim's answer, I'm more in agreement with the OP. `A specific type/kind` is always redundant.

If you disagree, think of this:

> It's not *just* a type of [noun], it's a *specific* type of [noun].

This specificity is because of what reason? The reason types or kinds is plural -- i.e., you can select one of them -- is because there are different types or kinds, and they are able to be specified. Although, they could be random groupings without the groups having individual designations. Regardless, it's *just one of multiple* `specific` types.

Furthermore, the article `a` is an indefinite article, and `specific` is definite. This means, regardless of the noun, `a specific` is an [oxymoron](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oxymoron#English).

Comment: Is it a type? A specific type? A very specific type? An extremely specific type? Does tautology count here?

Comment: A German Shepherd is a type of dog. A mutt of unknown pedigree is also a type of dog.  But a German Shepherd is also a specific type of dog whereas the mutt is not.

Answer (score 0):

A flowdiagran is a subtype of a diagram. Both are types and not tokens or instances. The drawing that I made is in instance of a flow diagram.
I would say that a flow diagram is a specific type of a diagram. "A flow diagram is a type of diagram " is street language but everybody understand what we mean.